# How would I transfer information like a variable from javascript to python using AJAX and Flask

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask

I am messing around with Flask and Ajax to see what I can do with it for a bigger project I'm working on. I am trying to get some data in a variable into my python program to be able to use and manipulate. I have a script in an html file that returns the current URL. How can I get the url into my python program with AJAX?

I will attach my relevant code below:

index.html

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>HELP</title>
</head>
<body>
    
    <p>I am {{person}} and i am {{age}} years old, I am a {{ql}}</p>

    <form name="passdata" action="." method="post">
        <label>Name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="name">
        <label>Age:</label>
        <input type="text" name="age">
        <label>Date of Birth:</label>
        <input type="text" name="dateofbirth">
        <input type="submit" value="submit">
    </form>

    <p id="demo"></p>

    <script>
        let geturl = window.
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = 
        "The full URL of this page is:<br>" + geturl;
    </script> //getting the current url

</body>
</html>
```

main.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request


app = Flask(__name__)
name = "random"
age = "21"
qualification = "software engineer"


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html', person=name, age=age, ql=qualification)


@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def getvalue():
    name2 = request.form['name']
    age = request.form['age']
    db = request.form['dateofbirth']
    return name2


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

let me know if you need any clarification. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Usually when you are sending variables to routes in flask you will have the route designed as:

```py
@app.route('/route_to_send_to/<variable>', methods=['GET'])
def route_to_send_to(variable):
    variable_sent = variable
    
    return jsonify({'variable':variable})
```

Another hint usually when working with ajax calls the response may be a json response which you can send back with jsonify.

All you need to do is call it to the route replacing  with the variable you want to send.

You can also send with Ajax a post request to have the data hidden, but then you will need to change the route to handle post requests.

The Ajax call may be something like:

```
        var url = '/route_to_send_to/ + name;
        return $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: url,
            }).then(function(data) {// Do something with the responce})
        });
```

Considering the comments below I might suggest you read this [article](https://towardsdatascience.com/using-python-flask-and-ajax-to-pass-information-between-the-client-and-server-90670c64d688) to get a better understanding of how flask and ajax work together.

Also This amazing [Flask tutorial by Miguel Grinberg](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world) is probably one of the best resources I have ever come across for learning flask, the framework and good conducts with it. It goes through everything from the absolute basic to extremely advanced topics and is well worth the time.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I implemented your suggestions here: `from flask import Flask, json, render_template, request


app = Flask(__name__)
name = "random"
age = "21"
qualification = "software engineer"


@app.route('/route_to_send_to/<variable>', methods=['GET'])
def route_to_send_to(variable):
    variable_sent = variable
    
    return json.jsonify({'variable':variable})


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
`

Comment: I've also added to the index.html as follows: `<script>
        let geturl = window.location.href
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = 
        "The full URL of this page is:<br>" + geturl;

        var url = '/route_to_send_to/' + name;
        return $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: url,
            }).then(function(data) {// Do something with the responce})
        }); 
    </script>`

Comment: But when running the server, I'm getting this error "The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again." Am I doing something wrong with the routing?

Comment: do you have ajax within the head <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script> this indicates that the url is routed wrong you need  to reformat the url t work correctly potentially durig debugging you could use 'http://localhost:5000/route_to_send_to/' + name; I think that is the port of flask but in deployment you will need to debug once more.

Comment: I have edited the answer with some resources that can help you gain a better understanding with flask and ajax.

Comment: Thank you so much for these resources. I'm usually a back end developer so front end is not usually my expertise. But I really do appreciate your help and patience!